# FullCalendar weird behavior with events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs, fullcalendar-5

I am using a full calendar with this configuration.

```
  config: {
    plugins: [
      interactionPlugin,
      dayGridPlugin,
      timeGridPlugin,
      listPlugin,
      momentPlugin,
      momentTimezonePlugin,
    ],
    initialView: "timeGridWeek",
    slotLabelFormat: "HH:mm",
    allDaySlot: false,
    slotDuration: "00:60:00",
    dayHeaderFormat: { weekday: "short" },
    initialDate: "1970-01-01",
    titleFormat: {
      weekday: "short",
    },
    // dayNamesShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
    dayMaxEventRows: true,
    eventOverlap: false,
    eventColor: "#458CC7",
    firstDay: 1,
    height: "auto",
    selectMirror: true,
    selectable: true,
    timeZone: "UTC",
    headerToolbar: {
      left: "",
      center: "",
      right: "",
    },
    editable: true,
    events: null,
    eventTimeFormat: {
      // like '14:30:00'
      hour: "2-digit",
      minute: "2-digit",
      hour12: false,
    },
  },
```

when I select an event, from start of the day, it comes as

[image]

a full day doesn't come with any ending value, when I start from the very start of the day, it comes with the very last hour, whereas I want it to show as

if the selected full day, start from 00:00 and ends at 23:59 and so on. what is wrong with my configurations.

Comment: Which version of fullCalendar are you using?

Comment: Also, you say _when I select an event, from start of the day, it comes as_...but then you show us a picture with 3 events on it. Which one are you talking about? And when you say "select", what exact action did you take? Do you mean you simply clicked on the 00:00 row? Or you click and drag, or what? Please try to be specific.

Comment: And also, you say _start from 00:00 and ends at 59:59_ ...but what do you mean? `59:59` is not a valid time.

Comment: I am using the latest version. Thursday and Saturday events are wrong.

Comment: 00:00 to 23:59 i mean

Comment: Ok so it's the "24:00" bit which is the problem you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using momentJS already, you can use a moment formatting string which will make it display 00:00 instead of 24:00 in the event time:

```
eventTimeFormat: "HH:mm"
```

Working demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/RwaPBQw

Comment: start an even from 00:00 to end see what will happen :)

Comment: also the problem is both events 24 bit as well as the saturdays event , please see it as well

Comment: _"start an even from 00:00 to end see what will happen"_ ...I did. It now shows as 00:00-whatever when you set it as I've shown above. Did you run my demo?

Comment: i have run the demo and if I select the full day. it shows 00-(nothing) and (nothing) = blank

Comment: I see what you mean. If I had to guess I'd say that's probably a bug. I can't find any setting or functionality which would control it. You can report bugs using the instructions here: https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs . In the meantime, I believe my answer has helped you with the first part of the problem (converting 24 to 00), so accepting or upvoting the  answer would be appreciated :-)